# How do I use DFeet?

Tags: application-development, dbus

I've been trying for a half hour to get D-Feet to open a service, *any* service with the Connect button. I feel I am misunderstanding this application at a basic level. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the File menu, select "Connect to session bus" or "Connect to system bus"

Answer (score 1):

You do not enter a service address into DFeet. The connect button is for the address of the System / Session bus. Yes, the overlap in D-Bus related vocabulary is arcane and stupid.

1. Get your System or Session Bus address. For regular applications, you're probably looking for the Session Bus address. Open a command line and enter:

   ```
   echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
   ```
2. Launch DFeet and hit the "Connect" button.

   [image]
3. Paste in your bus address from the command line output. Then press "Connect".

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can launch it directly by issuing the following at the command line:

```
d-feet -a $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```